# JavaScript - filter through an array with arguments using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to use the filter method on an array to loop through the array based on a variable number of arguments.

Below is my attempt at this:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var argArr = arr.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var filteredArray = arr.filter(function(val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < argArr.length; i++) {
        return val != argArr[i];
    };
  });
  console.log(filteredArray);
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

When I do this, only the first element of the arguments array is disposed of. This therefore returns:

```
[1, 3, 1, 3]
```

I have found a few examples online of possible ways to resolve this but they are vastly different from what I understand just yet. Is there any way to get mine to work, or even understand why the additional elements of the arguments array are not being called.

Comment: The "problem" you're experiencing is caused by the `return` statement effectively limiting the loop to _one_ iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `ES6` you can do it with [**rest**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters) operator and [**Array#includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...params){
    return arr.filter(item => !params.includes(item));
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

With your logic you can do like this. If `val` is equal to the current `argArr's` item then `return false`, if nothing was found after the loop: `return true`

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var argArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var filteredArray = arr.filter(function(val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < argArr.length; i++) {
         if(val === argArr[i]){
             return false;
         }
    };
    return true;
  });
  console.log(filteredArray);
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, exactly what I was looking to do!

Answer (score 0):

Because with your code you always test if current element in filter is equal or not equal to second parameter in function which is 2 and return true/false. Instead you can use `indexOf` to test if current element in filter is inside arguments array.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var argArr = arr.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var filteredArray = arr.filter(function(val) {
    return argArr.indexOf(val) == -1
  });
  console.log(filteredArray);
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your this line 
`return val != argArr[i];`

Change logic like this , it will avoid to do extra looping also .

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var argArr = arr.slice.call(arguments, 1); debugger
  var filteredArray = arr.filter(function(val) {
    return !(argArr.indexOf(val) >= 0);
  });
  console.log(filteredArray);
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```